# Homomorphisms from a $p$-group to $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-cohomology, p-groups

I'm doing a problem on group cohomology and have reduced it to the following: if $P$ is a $p$-group then $\textrm{Hom}(P,\mathbb{F}_p) \simeq P/\Phi(P)$ where $\Phi(P)$ is the Frattini subgroup of $P$. I know any homomorphism from $P \to \mathbb{F}_p$ is uniquely determined by a maximal subgroup of $P$. Also its easy to see $\textrm{Hom}(P/[P,P],\mathbb{F}_p) \simeq \textrm{Hom}(P,\mathbb{F}_p)$, so this may help given that $\Phi(P) = P^p[P,P]$. But I'm not particularly sure how to proceed. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: When you write "morphism" here, do you mean a group homomorphism?

Comment: yes, I'll edit my question.

Comment: You are almost there: note that if $\phi: P \to \mathbb{F}_{p}$ is a homomorphism, then $\phi(x^{p}) = p \phi(x)  = 0$, where $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ is written additively.

Comment: Hmm, thanks, that's helpful. I'm trying to define a map from $P$ (or $P/[P,P]$) to the Hom-set. Is this the right approach?

Comment: I think it is a well-known that a finite Abelian group is isomorphic to its dual group.

Comment: Sorry, now I'm a little confused. How is the dual group related?

Comment: Can $\textrm{Hom}(P,\mathbb{F}_p)$ be realized as a subgroup of the dual group?

Comment: Took about a minute to confirm the two groups are isomorphic. Thanks for your help!